# Arcpy ChangePrivileges_management not working

Tags: arcpy

I was trying to revoke access for a user using Python script, but it does not seem to work.
I mean the script runs successfully without any error, but does not what it's intended to...

Here're the steps I follow:

1. I am connecting with the schema owner, and revoking access for another user, say 'B' for a particular dataset [Python]
2. The script runs OK...without any error (exits with code 0)
3. Connect with user B to chk if it's worked...and NO, I can see the data still

Any idea why its happening?
I've tried with exclusive lock; and ArcCatalog...even then the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have a possible reason for the privileges not being applied.

In a special case of REVOKING ACCESS (my case!), you need to have exclusive lock on the schema. So if other users are still connected, you won't be able to revoke access to a FC or DATASET.

But shouldn't the tool fail (as it does with other functions like *Create FeatureClass* in similar scenario)...? Design question...may be.

If the GDB access is governed by ROLES at the database level, it would take precedence during privilege modification via script or ArcCatalog...the solution would be using the role names while granting/revoking access.

Comment: UPDATE: Revoke does not work even after granting exclusive access i.e. killing all other sessions to the particular schema! I've tried with Python script; using ArcCatalog, but both of them have the same result...NOTHING!  Any guesses why such a behaviour?

Comment: UPDATE 2: Installed ArcGIS 10 SP3, "just in case" it is a patching issue....but no, it is still the same!!! x-(

Comment: UPDATE 3: I think I have the answer now...if the GDB access is governed by ROLES at the database level, it would take precedence to the privilege modification via script or ArcCatalog...the solution would be modifying the role to achieve the result!

Comment: Please consider editing your answer to include the solution you arrived at and of course you can (and should) accept your own answer!